# How to visualize my Python code structure or flow as a graph?

Tags: python

I have a python function and I want to see the flow or the structure of my code as a graph. I know that it is possible in C/C++ using Graphviz. But I am not aware of a similar tool for python.

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz also works for Python 3.7+ [here](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same tool exists for Python, it can also be easily installed via pip by typing `pip install graphviz` "or [Alternative downloading methods](https://graphviz.org/download/)"

Here is a simple documentation with many examples that may help you as well. **[Link](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)**.

Comment: Thank you for this. However, the idea is that I want the tool to convert my code into for example a function call graph or instruction graph automatically. Not using the tool to draw the graph